# Generally Non-Integrable Bounded Function

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I've notice that most examples of Non-Integrable functions always have to do with not being bounded in a region or not being Integrable in a very specific sense (like in the Riemannian sense). All the examples I've seen for non-Lebesgue integrable functions have to do with issues at boundedness. Can someone tell me a good example of a non-Lebesgue integrable function that doesn't suffer from this specific issue.

More generally: is there a function where it is not possible to define a concept of "good" notion of integrability over a set on which it is bounded. By good I mean that it obtains the value you would expect if you took the "average" value (in the intuitive way one would do it that includes ignoring measure zero parts) and multiplied it by the size of the set.

Comment: If a function is measurable and bounded it is integrable.  It sounds like you are asking for examples of non-measurable functions.

Comment: There are several things that may spoil the standard definition**s** of integral. Not being bounded is one, non-measurable another, a function can be both measurable and bounded ($f(x)=(-1)^{[x]}$ on $\mathbb{R}$) and still not being integrable. So, finiteness of the size of the domain is also important.

Answer (score 1):

Try the indicator function of a [non-measurable set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set).